# Cannot Launch in AVD in the Emulator

Tags: android-studio, react-native, android-emulator

[This is the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NYBzL.jpg)

Hello guys I have a problem about Android Studio. Whenever I want to open Emulator, It doesn't work and says (or you can click the picture):

> Emulator: warning: host doesn't support requested feature:
>   CPUID.80000001H:ECX.sse4a [bit 6]

I couldn't solve this problem. I am using Ubuntu 16.04. I have installed SDK and of course Android Studio. Thanks for answers.

Comment: seems related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44893322/do-x86-android-avds-work-on-linux-on-amd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've faced the same problem. This warning isn't a reason for emulator not working. Check virtualization support in your system as described in https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-acceleration.html and https://help.ubuntu.com/community/KVM/Installation