# Emulator, android studio

Tags: android-studio

When I try run app in Android Studio I get warning:
Emulator: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.80000001H:ECX.abm [bit 5]

Does anyone know how to fix it?

I'm working on Linux Mint.

Comment: read this [possible duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44893322/do-x86-android-avds-work-on-linux-on-amd?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Answer (score 0):

I played with (a pristine chroot of) Ubuntu 16.04 myself now. Without package grub-pc-bin installed, QEMU failed to boot the rescue image saying Could not read from CDROM (code 0004). After sudo apt-get install grub-pc-bin it booted fine. So I enforce use of platform i386-pc in the code now and produce an error if it's found missing.

I consider this ticket fixed. If you still run into issues, please make new tickets (with terminal output, Ubuntu version, and a screenshot of te QEMU window). Thanks!

[more...](https://github.com/hartwork/grub2-theme-preview/issues/14)

Answer (score 0):

You can fix this by replacing your CPU to any, that support LZCNT feature. More detailed answer I posted here: [Android Virtual Device ERROR on Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51962810/android-virtual-device-error-on-android-studio/52828980#52828980)