# Android Virtual Device ERROR on Android Studio

Tags: android, device, virtual, android-virtual-device

When I try the open Virtual Device, I see the same error. What can I do?

That error :

```
Emulator: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.80000001H:ECX.abm [bit 5]
```

I can't fix my problem :/ I asked yesterday but anyone answer it :/

Note : Virtualization Technology is enabled and KVM is OK.

Comment: I should let the poster know that I am on Linux Mint 19, I have been using android studio for two weeks before that message started popping up. I think it may be a plugin.

Answer (score 13):

This error is referring to CPU feature called LZCNT. It was introduced in Intel processors since Haswell (2013) and in AMD since 2007. So if your CPU is older or to any other reason does not support LZCNT - you will get this warning. 
You can check if your CPU support LZCNT instruction by executing the following command (Linux):

```
cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep abm
```

LZCNT can not be checked directly but it is included in the ABM flag (Advanced Bit Manipulations) which indicates both POPCNT and LZCNT are present. So if command output is blank - LZCNT is not supported.

Comment: So, Is there any option to disable the warning if I use android studio.

Comment: @zeleven unfortunately no.

Comment: I have the same issue but the android studio emulator works for me even I don't support the LZCNT thing.

Comment: It may be you are targeting a different api level? [Allegedly](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/17995#issuecomment-415958984) LZCNT became *actually* required starting from 8.1.

Answer (score 0):

idk if this is still an acutal problem.

I've tried many different things to solve that problem on my machine, but nothing really worked out for me. I'm still not able to configure my emulator stettings but i'll find a way.

Back to the problem AVD not working:

I'm running Ubuntu 22.04 on a Aspire-M7720 (Core I7-900) 14Gb RAM and a GeForce GTX 960

The solution was quite simple: I've just installed the proprietary drivers for my GPU and now it's working. IDK why it's working now, but all Images are working perfectly fine now. Hope it helps you