# How to fix Emulator: qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.80000001H:ECX.abm [bit 5]

Tags: android, linux, android-studio, android-emulator

I have this message in the console, which did not appear before formatting the computer.

```
Ubuntu 18.04, Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-3470 CPU @ 3.20GHz, cpu_cores: 4
8GB Ram, qemu-kvm x86_64.

Emulator: qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.80000001H:ECX.abm [bit 5]
```

Comment: You can see a potential answer at [Emulator: qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.80000001H:ECX.abm [bit 5]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51962810/android-virtual-device-error-on-android-studio/52828980#52828980)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I had the same problem on MacOS.  Adding `-cpu host` to `qemu-system-x86_64` solved it.

For example:

`qemu-system-x86_64 -m 4000 -vga virtio -accel hvf -usb -device usb -tablet -drive file=ubuntu.qcow2,if=virtio -cpu host`

Solution found on github [here](https://github.com/GNS3/gns3-server/issues/1639).

Comment: What does `-cpu host` do?